# Can I have two separate applications for iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, user-interface, ipad

I have completed an iPad app which only available on iPad iTune store.

But client wants to have different design but similar functionality application for iPhone as well. Some of new feature must be added to iPhone version. I can use most of the functionalities in iPad version and have a new project and build iPhone from scratch!

My requirements will be change during time. New requirements could be for both or either of them. Therefore, I need to add new features in both applications time to time and maintain both applications as well. This app is pretty much complex with more than 150 classes. I need some advice to know is it better to have only one application to works on both devices or it is better practice to have separate project for each iPhone and iPad?

**EDIT**
I want to use split view controller and vertical menu bar in iPad  and side menu and horizontal menu bar in iPhone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to have two separate iPhone/iPad apps on the store, just make two targets of your application. This will mean you'll probably will use two different storyboards, but that's up to you. Go to your project settings and make two separate targets - one for iPad, one for iPhone. Edit the target general settings where one should only deploy for iPad while the other for iPhone. Posted some pictures below:

[image: Making new target]

[image: Example Build[2]]

You'll want to also go to Manage Schemes, remove the current schemes you have and add the targets you just made. Then set these macros in your iPhone build so you can just edit one code base without needing to edit both the phone and tablet code -

[image: Macros]

Some example Code:

```
// Just for Phone Target
#ifdef PHONE
- (void)somePhoneMethod;
#endif

// For both phone and tablet device
- (void)aMethod;
```

I'd like to add to what everyone has said and if there isn't too much difference just make a universal app.

Answer (score 1):

> Use Auto layout and maintain in a single storyboard.
>
> If you know about classes ,Autolayout Strong then my preference is
>   AutoLayout.
>
> It will reduce your time and easiest handling.

[image]

this is Classes here if you like to do vertical layout only for ipad means ,you need to select like this

[image]

like this you can choose only for ipad,iphones,portrait,landscape like this :),Its upto your decision.

Comment: I want to use split view controller and vertical menu bar in iPad  and side menu and horizontal menu bar in iPhone. Layout is totally different. How can I do it?

Comment: @Bernard definitely you can do it using classes wait a minute.

Comment: @Bernard check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If UI is same for both so its better to use existing just check in classes for iPad and iPhone.

Comment: I want to use split view controller and vertical menu bar in iPad  and side menu and horizontal menu bar in iPhone. So UI is slightly different!